# How to reduce Call volume below lowest setting?

Tags: motorola-moto-g, volume-control, headphones, volume

How can I reduce the minimum call volume while using a headset on Android?  I am using a Moto G5 Plus, but I am searching generally for all models a way to adjust in-call volume beyond the default constraints. Thank you!

Call Volume is too loud on minimum setting, and obviously dangerous above 50%.
Music Volume is excellent and extremely low at minimum level.

Model Details:

- Moto G5 Plus
- Purchased from Motorola directly on 2017-07-09
- Android 7.0 Nougat
- Build number NPNS25.137-35-5

Additional detail and request from manufacturer at [Minimum Call Volume Too High and Loud with Headset or Headphones - Moto G5 Plus - Lenovo Community](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/Minimum-Call-Volume-Too-High-and-Loud-with-Headset-or-Headphones/m-p/3743602#M8057)

Here is what I have tried so far,

- Multiple high quality headphones
- Sony MDR-V6
- Apple In-Ear Headphones with Remote and Mic
- Safe mode - Long press power, followed by Long press on "Power off" dialog box.
- Skype Calls - Problem is the same, even in Skype, which relies on the same "Call" volume slider.

Alternative Phones with same calls, headphones, no issues.

- iPhone 6
- Nexus 5x with Android 7.1.2

Apps which do *not* work:

With options which look like they will work:

- DSP Manager

Without options which look like they will work:

- Fine Volume Control V2
- Volume Control +
- Audio Concert
- Music Volume EQ + Bass Booster

Additional Related Problems: See lenovo post as I am unable to post additional links with current reputation.  [Minimum Call Volume Too High and Loud with Headset or Headphones - Moto G5 Plus - Lenovo Community](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-G5-Moto-G5-Plus/Minimum-Call-Volume-Too-High-and-Loud-with-Headset-or-Headphones/m-p/3743602#M8057)

Considering additional hardware to solve:
Koss VC20 Volume Control - [https://www.amazon.com/Koss-155954-VC20-Volume-Control/dp/B00001P4XH](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00001P4XH)

Thanks for any help!